# Trying to populate bootstrap carousel with images using angular templates

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to dynamically populate a bootstrap carousel with screenshots. Everything is working, besides the actual switching of the screenshots. I found out that this is caused by the `<screenshots>` tag being placed by angular. If I would delete this `<screenshots>` manually it would work. Is there a way to do this programatically? Or is my aproach just not good/wrong?

project-template.component.html (carousel part)

```
<div id="test" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <template #screenshots></template>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#test" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#test" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

project-template.component.ts (carousel part)

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentFactory, ComponentRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ScreenshotsComponent } from './screenshots/screenshots.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-template',
  templateUrl: './project-template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-template.component.css']
})
export class ProjectTemplateComponent {

  @Input() screenshots: Array<Object>;
  @Output() output = new EventEmitter();


  @ViewChild("screenshots", { read: ViewContainerRef }) containerScreenshots;
  componentRefScreenshots: ComponentRef<ScreenshotsComponent>;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.containerScreenshots.clear();

    for(let i = 1; i < this.screenshots[0]["count"] + 1; i++){
      const factory: ComponentFactory<ScreenshotsComponent> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ScreenshotsComponent);
      this.componentRefScreenshots = this.containerScreenshots.createComponent(factory);
      let put = this.componentRefScreenshots.instance
      put.output.subscribe(event => console.log(event));
      if(i == 1){
        put.ac = " active"
      }
      put.number = i
      put.project = this.screenshots[0]['project'] as string;
      put.projectType = this.screenshots[0]['project-type'] as string;
    }

  }

}
```

screenshots.component.html

```
<div class="carousel-item{{ac}}">
  <img class="d-block w-100 image" src="../assets/{{projectType}}/{{project}}/Screenshot-{{number}}.png" alt="{{number}} slide"
    style="max-width: 15%; max-height: 15%;">
</div>
```

screenshots.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'screenshots',
  templateUrl: './screenshots.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./screenshots.component.css']
})
export class ScreenshotsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() projectType: string = "loading...";
  @Input() project: string = "loading...";
  @Input() number: number = -1;
  @Input() ac: string = "";
  @Output() output = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

the result:

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="test">
  <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="carousel-inner">
    <template _ngcontent-c1=""></template>
    <screenshots _nghost-c6="">
      <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="carousel-item active">
        <img _ngcontent-c6="" class="d-block w-100 image" style="max-width: 15%; max-height: 15%;" src="../assets/android-projects/school-diary/Screenshot-1.png"
          alt="1 slide">
      </div>
    </screenshots>
    <screenshots _nghost-c6="">
      <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="carousel-item">
        <img _ngcontent-c6="" class="d-block w-100 image" style="max-width: 15%; max-height: 15%;" src="../assets/android-projects/school-diary/Screenshot-2.png"
          alt="2 slide">
      </div>
    </screenshots>
    <screenshots _nghost-c6="">
      <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="carousel-item">
        <img _ngcontent-c6="" class="d-block w-100 image" style="max-width: 15%; max-height: 15%;" src="../assets/android-projects/school-diary/Screenshot-3.png"
          alt="3 slide">
      </div>
    </screenshots>
    <screenshots _nghost-c6="">
      <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="carousel-item">
        <img _ngcontent-c6="" class="d-block w-100 image" style="max-width: 15%; max-height: 15%;" src="../assets/android-projects/school-diary/Screenshot-4.png"
          alt="4 slide">
      </div>
    </screenshots>
    <screenshots _nghost-c6="">
      <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="carousel-item">
        <img _ngcontent-c6="" class="d-block w-100 image" style="max-width: 15%; max-height: 15%;" src="../assets/android-projects/school-diary/Screenshot-5.png"
          alt="5 slide">
      </div>
    </screenshots>
    <screenshots _nghost-c6="">
      <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="carousel-item">
        <img _ngcontent-c6="" class="d-block w-100 image" style="max-width: 15%; max-height: 15%;" src="../assets/android-projects/school-diary/Screenshot-6.png"
          alt="6 slide">
      </div>
    </screenshots>
    <screenshots _nghost-c6="">
      <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="carousel-item">
        <img _ngcontent-c6="" class="d-block w-100 image" style="max-width: 15%; max-height: 15%;" src="../assets/android-projects/school-diary/Screenshot-7.png"
          alt="7 slide">
      </div>
    </screenshots>
    <screenshots _nghost-c6="">
      <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="carousel-item">
        <img _ngcontent-c6="" class="d-block w-100 image" style="max-width: 15%; max-height: 15%;" src="../assets/android-projects/school-diary/Screenshot-8.png"
          alt="8 slide">
      </div>
    </screenshots>
  </div>
  <a _ngcontent-c1="" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev" href="#test" role="button">
    <span _ngcontent-c1="" aria-hidden="true" class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a _ngcontent-c1="" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next" href="#test" role="button">
    <span _ngcontent-c1="" aria-hidden="true" class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to use **bootstrap** and not **ngx-bootstrap**.
I think you would be better off using the latter one, it is much more adapted to angular :)

Secondly, I don't see why you are trying to force the component creation procedure using the 'complicated' `ComponentFactory` and so. Is there a reason for that? Just because if not, I would rather use the **Dynamic Slides** example from the **ngx-bootstrap** docs:

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel#dynamic-slides

So basically you'd just have a for loop (ngFor) in the template file, which generates the slides dynamically, depending on how many slide data you have in the bounded input.
The `carousel` tag has an `activeSlide` property, which is two-way bindable, so you can easily control the desired slide index to be active.

EDIT:
If the only problem is how to remove the wrapping tag of the `screenshots` component then you can do the following:

1. adjust the screenshots component to make it work as directive too:

instead of

```
selector: 'screenshots',
```

use

```
selector: 'screenshots, [screenshots-directive]',
```

2. usage

instead of

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <template #screenshots></template>
</div>
```

write a for loop as mentioned earlier:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let screenshot of screenshots; 
       let i = index" screenshots-directive [number]="i" [project]="screenshot.project">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I took the `carousel-item` div out of the `screenshots` component. It is necessary because the for loop needs to be added to a html tag. Normally the `ng-template` and `ng-container` tags could be used when you want to use a for loop but you dont want the for loop's container to be rendered. However, it does not seem to work together with a directive, such as the `screenshots-directive`, I don't know why.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't know that there is a bootstrap version specifically for angular. I'll give it a try and report whether it worked or not.

Comment: Okay this worked very well, thanks. But is there a way to easily animate the transition between the images, just like the conventional bootstrap does? I didn't found anything about that in the documentation of the carousel.

Comment: I just read about it too and it seems it hasn't been implemented.. So in case your only problem was how to remove the wrapping tag of your component and you the 'standard' bootstrap would do the job, I have extended my answer :)

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: you have to add the class `active` to exactly one element, otherwise no picture will be displayed. I solved the problem by adding this to `screenshots.component.ts` in the ngOnInit method: `document.getElementsByClassName('w-100')[0].parentElement.classList.add('active');`. Not very sleek but it's working now. Maybe you could add this in some form to your answer.